# zip -9 compression isn't reducing file size

Tags: linux, zip

I have a file which I want to compress into a zip archive however this is being automatically sent via Amazon SES and occasionally the email is rejected due to the following:

Which seems to mean that the email is larger than the 10MB limit. The zip archive is currently created using standard level 6 compression, I would like to change this to use maximum compression (level 9) however it doesn't seem to change the archive size.

Original (level 6) command:

```
zip standard.zip somefile.txt 
  adding: somefile.txt (deflated 42%)
```

Attempted (level 9) command:

```
zip -9 9.zip somefile.txt 
  adding: somefile.txt (deflated 42%)
```

Results:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 5.0M Jan 27 23:20 standard.zip
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 5.0M Jan 27 23:19 9.zip
```

As you can probably tell from the results I'm running on an AWS EC2 instance with Amazon Linux.

I expected the `9.zip` archive to be significantly smaller, what am I doing wrong?

In addition the fact performance will be impacted when changing compression levels is not really an issue for the use case for this process.

The file has to be a `.zip` file, the recipient does not what another archive format.

Answer (score 2):

> I expected the `9.zip` archive to be significantly smaller, what am I doing wrong?

What you're doing wrong is expecting maximum level of zlib compression to offer significant compression over the best medium level. This simply isn't true, as can be shown empirically. Highly compressible data already compresses *very* well at level 6, and non-compressible data doesn't benefit in any noticeable manner from level 9.

If you really wanted to compress it a lot then you could use a zip tool built against [Zopfli](https://github.com/google/zopfli) instead of zlib, but expect compression to take much, much longer.